# How to use SQL indexes to seek a starting point

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

In VB we used to be able to open an ACCESS DAO.Recordset and specify an index. Once opened, we could seek to a specific record in the index and then walk through the dataset backwards and forwards from there using the index.

```
Dim dnj As DAO.Recordset
dnj = DB.OpenRecordset("ITEMS")
dnj.Index = "IndexIW"
dnj.Seek("=", "Item 17a", "ABC")
dnj.MovePrevious()
```

Is there an equivalent in modern databases like SQL Server using Indexes to read through records? I tried this but the error says the API for indexes is not supported.

```
Dim iTbl As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim key(1) As String
iTbl.ActiveConnection = cnn
iTbl.CursorLocation = ADOR.CursorLocationEnum.adUseServer
iTbl.Open("ITEMS")
iTbl.Index = "IndexIW"
key(0) = "Item 17a"
key(1) = "ABC"
iTbl.Seek(key, ADODB.SeekEnum.adSeekFirstEQ)
iTbl.MovePrevious()
```

What I would really like to be able to do is something like:

```
SELECT NEXT 10 ITEM_NUM, ITEM_TYPE, ITEM_DESC FROM ITEMS WHERE (PK_ITEM) = ("Item 17a","ABC")
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 10 ITEM_NUM, ITEM_TYPE, ITEM_DESC FROM ITEM STARTING WITH PK_ITEM = ("Item 17a","ABC")
```

But I don't know how to do that

Comment: What library are you using in your second example. I assume it's not DAO. It seems like it would be easier to just order your result set through SQL and filter it there. Surely it would be quicker then monkeying in your resultset on the client side.

Comment: I am using an ADODB Recordset. I can't use an order by clause because the table in question has hundreds of thousands of rows. What I really want to do is to open the Index, search for a value and then extract records on either side of the index key.

Comment: It still feels silly. Get the records you desire via sql instead of pulling hundreds of thousands of records across the wire and manipulating your records set. It sounds like a problem that could be solved relatively easily with a SQL statement where you will be utilizing the power of your database to grab the records you need, where that logic should be done.

Comment: I'd be happy to use the power of the database. Help me out with the query then. I have 500,000 items in a table. The PK is item number and item type. The sort order is item number, item type. I want to view item [12345, ABC] and the 20 items in the order before and after that item I don't have any idea what the item. numbers or types of the other items are.

Comment: you could do a row_number() over...figure out the row number for the one you want...and filter for similar row_numbers but youd be doing that on 500000 records...that's not an ideal operation...do you have a better concept to say 20 before and 20 after...using the actual data that's there (maybe a date column for example)?